# upload captured image to FTP using ftpClient in android

Tags: android, ftp-client

i want to upload captured image from an android phone to Ftp Server i have written following code i m facing error at this line ftp.store(remote,input) after this line 
    i m getting replycode=550 file unavialable i m using apache commons-net 3.3 library i have tried
    same with WebClient in .net it works fine but in java its gives me dis error(550) i have searched many sites but no help i even called hosting service they said no problem from there side i stucked from last 1 day plz correct me what i am missing here......

my code :

```
private void UploadImage(){

    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

    try {
        ftp.connect("hostname",21);// Using port no=21
        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();  //here i m getting 220

        ftp.login("abc", "abc");   

        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();      //here i m getting 230

        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);



        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        File sfile = new File(PhotoPath);  //here i m getting /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/CameraSample/abc769708880.jpg

        String filename = sfile.getName();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sfile);
        boolean aRtn=ftp.storeFile("ftpPath"+sfile.getName(), fis);// return true if successful

        reply = ftp.getReplyCode(); // here im getting 550

        if(aRtn == true)
        {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
        }   
        fis.close();    
        ftp.disconnect();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That exception seems to be thrown when you try to perform network operations (such as FTP) from your main thread. This is not allowed for performance reasons (so that the application doesn't appear to lock up to the user, when performing an action which may take a while). Assuming you are using Honeycomb or higher, you would need to move the code that makes the connection into its own child thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

[http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

Comment: i m using AsyncTask to upload that image i not getting this error NetworkOnMainThreadException.....